# cobalt create surface on android

Tags: android, cobalt

I want to port cobalt to Android, After solving many compilation problems, my cobalt has already run on the Android, but there is an error has occurred when invoking eglMakeCurrent.

This is my mainly codes for creating Surface:

```
……
sp<SurfaceComposerClient> session = new SurfaceComposerClient;
sp<SurfaceControl> control = session->createSurface(
        String8("CobaltArea"), 1280, 720,
        PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565, ISurfaceComposerClient::eOpaque);
sp<Surface> surface = control->getSurface();
……
surface_ = eglCreateWindowSurface(display_, config_, surface.get(), NULL);
……
```

It's correct when invoking eglCreateWindowSurface（cobalt/renderer/backend/egl/display.cc） to create EGLSurface object.
but there is a error when invoking eglMakeCurrent(cobalt/renderer/backend/egl/graphics_context.cc)

```
void GraphicsContextEGL::SafeEglMakeCurrent(RenderTargetEGL* surface) {
  EGLSurface egl_surface = surface->GetSurface();

  // This should only be used with egl surfaces (not framebuffer objects).
  DCHECK_NE(egl_surface, EGL_NO_SURFACE);
  DCHECK_EQ(surface->GetPlatformHandle(), 0);

  if (surface->is_surface_bad()) {
    // A surface may become invalid in the middle of shutdown processing. If
    // this is a known bad surface, then bind the null surface just as if this
    // is the first time it is found to be bad.
    egl_surface = null_surface_->GetSurface();
    EGL_CALL(eglMakeCurrent(display_, egl_surface, egl_surface, context_));
    return;
  }

  eglMakeCurrent(display_, egl_surface, egl_surface, context_);
  EGLint make_current_error = eglGetError();
  if (make_current_error != EGL_SUCCESS) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "eglMakeCurrent ERROR: " << make_current_error;
    if (make_current_error == EGL_BAD_ALLOC ||
        make_current_error == EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW) {
      LOG(ERROR) << "eglMakeCurrent raised either EGL_BAD_ALLOC or "
                    "EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW, continuing with null surface "
                    "under the assumption that our window surface has become "
                    "invalid due to a suspend or shutdown being triggered.";
      surface->set_surface_bad();
      egl_surface = null_surface_->GetSurface();
      EGL_CALL(eglMakeCurrent(display_, egl_surface, egl_surface, context_));
    } else {
      NOTREACHED() << "Unexpected error when calling eglMakeCurrent().";
    }
  }
}
```

The make_current_error is EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW, I want to know how to solve this problem, Could someone give some advice?
By the way,the version is Cobalt 14.

Comment: Cobalt will call SbWindowGetPlatformHandle() to get the native window handle, which is platform-specific.  Perhaps that is not connected properly?  Cobalt will pass the result of this function in as the third parameter to eglCreateWindowSurface().  For example, this should be something like ANativeWindow.

Comment: As I known, Cobalt gets the native window handle as the third param when invoking eglCreateWindowSurface. but I find this is a function which is platform-specific, it's not necessary for me. So I create the surface to  eglCreateWindowSurface() directly, and there isn't any error, the return value of eglGetError() is EGL_SUCCESS,

Comment: I have modified my codes for creating the surface, like this: sp<ANativeWindow> surface = control->getSurface(); but there are some log messages from the framework before calling eglMakeCurrent():  "BufferQueueProducer: [CobaltArea] query: BufferQueue has been abandoned", I think that the system has released the Surface buffer, so eglMakeCurrent() has the EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW error.

Comment: Hi there...  If you mean that you're modifying the common Cobalt code to pass in something other than SbWindowGetPlatformHandle(), then unfortunately you are on your own as we are only able to support the code as-is.  However if this is the case, you are strongly encouraged to find a way to implement SbWindowGetPlatformHandle() such that it fits your platform, since that will make it easier for you to update to future versions of Cobalt.

Comment: The question has solved, it's my stupid code's fault bring about this error. my cobalt has already loaded youtube page now. As you said, I need to find a way to implement SbWindowGetPlatformHandle() to update the future version, thank you for your advice.